# Oracle SQL: CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: sql, oracle, case, ora-00923

I'm trying to code a query which will display employees who work as developers (`'%_PROG'`) or managers (`'%_MAN'`).  My query is fine except for the 2nd line with `CASE WHEN THEN`. I'm getting the error message:

> ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected

so the problem must be with the second line, which is:

```
(CASE WHEN JOB_ID LIKE '%_PROG' THEN "Developer" ELSE "Manager" END) JOB_ID
```

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT 'Employee# ' || EMPLOYEE_ID 
       || ' named ' || FIRST_NAME
       || ' ' || LAST_NAME || ' who is ' 
       || CASE WHEN JOB_ID LIKE '%_PROG' THEN "Developer" ELSE "Manager" END 
       || ' will have a new salary of $'
       || ROUND((SALARY  +((SALARY/100)*25)),-2) AS "Employees with higher salary"
  FROM EMPLOYEES 
 WHERE JOB_ID LIKE '%_PROG' OR JOB_ID LIKE '%_MAN'
   AND (SALARY >= 3000 AND SALARY <= 5000)
 ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

The output should look like:

```
 Employee# 103 named Anna Clark who is Developer will have a new salary of  $006,100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an error in where clause. 'Developer' is redundant before OR

Comment: @OleksiiAza fixed that one but still getting an error. any idea?

Comment: also I believe that you should use single quotes in your 'CASE THEN' statement when you specify the result. E.g. 'Developer' and 'Manager'

Comment: @OleksiiAza oh yeah, that was it! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use single quotes in our statement:

`(CASE WHEN JOB_ID LIKE '%_PROG' THEN 'Developer' ELSE 'Manager' END) JOB_ID`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean columns, "Developer" and "Manager" are ok. If you meant strings, enclose them in single quotes.

You are not creating a column but concatenating the CASE expression with other expressions, so drop the `JOB_ID` after it that was originally meant as column alias. *(as I see now, you have edited it away)*